# Having trouble de-bugging an infinite loop

Tags: python, list, loops, infinite-loop

The code below takes the existing list, and maps the combinations of potential paths given the two lists A/B. It works great thus far but am having trouble dealing with an infinite loop when I add values to A&B.

```
existing_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]

A = [4,4, 5,6]
B = [5,6, 6,7]


def map_multiple(sublist):
    subsets = []
    anyMatches = False
    for (key, value) in zip(A, B):
        if key == sublist[-1]:
                new_sets = map_multiple(sublist + [value])
                subsets.extend(new_sets)
                anyMatches = True
    if not anyMatches:
        return [sublist]
    return subsets

new_list = []
for i in range(len(existing_list)):
    sublist = existing_list[i]
    allSubsets = map_multiple(sublist)
    new_list.extend(allSubsets)

new_list = list(set(map(tuple, new_list))) # Convert to set and back to list to remove    duplicates
new_list = [list(x) for x in new_list] # Convert back to list of lists

print(new_list)

#[[2, 3, 4, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Trying to retain the same output, I want to change the inputs of A&B to:

```
A = [4,4, 5,6,7]
B = [5,6, 6,7,6]
```

In this case the 7,6 on the last element of A&B will loop back into the main list and create an infinite loop. Any suggestions on maintaining the same output but stopping if any of the elements in A are already previous appended version of the existing list, therefore not creating an infinite loop?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`. This isn't related to the problem, just general advice about pythonic programming.

Comment: I don't see how you can have an infinite loop anywhere. Both of the `for` loops have specific limits. Do you mean infinite recursion?

Comment: What do these lists represent? I don't see how the output relates to the inputs.

Comment: When you make a recursive call, you need it to work on a provably smaller problem, and you need to reach and handle a base case. You are instead having map_multiple(sublist) call map_multiple(sublist + more stuff) which is the opposite of what you're supposed to do.

Comment: Your code is mapping 6 -> 7 *and* 7 -> 6, which should make it obvious why it causes an infinite cycle. From the information you have given in your question though, it's hard to see why this is considered a bug. As far as I can tell, your code should behave this way because that's what the task appears to require. Could you please edit your question with a detailed explanation of what exactly your code is trying to do, because currently we don't have enough information to help you fix your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for each unique path for the given inputs, you must explicitly disallow cycles, meaning you cannot revisit a node you have previously visited. This involves adding a simple condition to your code: `value not in sublist`. This will check if a value you are trying has already been visited and if so, will prevent it from being revisited.

Full function:

```py
def map_multiple(sublist):
    subsets = []
    anyMatches = False
    for (key, value) in zip(A, B):
        if key == sublist[-1] and value not in sublist:
            new_sets = map_multiple(sublist + [value])
            subsets.extend(new_sets)
            anyMatches = True
    if not anyMatches:
        return [sublist]
    return subsets
```

Also, please do not post duplicate questions, just respond to the comments on your main post in the future. If you have any further questions about this answer, please leave a comment.