# Infinite loop breakdown

Tags: python, list, loops, infinite-loop, break

Help with an infinite loop, I want to stop the function if it equals the first elements in the list in existing_list.

```
existing_list = [[ '10000714484,10000714481']]

A = df_test['A']
B = df_test['B']


def map_multiple(sublist, visited,max_depth=10):
    subsets = []
    anyMatches = False
    for (key, value) in zip(A, B):
        if key == sublist[-1] and value not in visited:
            new_visited = set(visited)
            new_visited.add(value)
            new_sets = map_multiple(sublist + [value], new_visited)
            subsets.extend(new_sets)
            anyMatches = True
    if not anyMatches:
        return [sublist]
    return subsets


new_list = []
for i in range(len(existing_list)):
    sublist = existing_list[i]
    allSubsets = map_multiple(sublist, set(sublist))
    new_list.extend(allSubsets)

new_list = list(set(map(tuple, new_list))) # Convert to set and back to list to remove     duplicates
new_list = [list(x) for x in new_list] # Convert back to list of lists

print(new_list)
```

Right now I am running this an it somehow has turned into in infinite loop. I know there are elements in B that contain 10000714484, but I am not sure which elements.

If it loops back around to 10000714484, I want the loop to stop.

Comment: Is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76219618/having-trouble-de-bugging-an-infinite-loop)?

Comment: None of the loops in this code are "infinite".

Comment: You need some way of remembering all the nodes you've visited. So if you visit the same node again, you stop.

Comment: It really only matters if it loops to the 1st elements in existing lists

Comment: You didn't include df_test, so I can't do much here. But I am confused by the text of your question referencing "10000714484" in existing_list, because that is not a value in existing_list.

Comment: df tests include 3000 objects but 10000714484 is included

Comment: I just said it's not in existing_list. I didn't say it wasn't in df_tests.

Comment: Everything loops back to "10000714484" which is in existing list, so if it loops and it is 10000714484  then I want it to stop if that makes sense.

Comment: Stop calling this infinite looping, it's infinite recursion. It may seem like infinite looping because you're adding to the list each time, so each recursion level loops over a longer list.

Comment: Appologies barmar

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having trouble de-bugging an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76219618/having-trouble-de-bugging-an-infinite-loop)